# Drupal and ParallaxJS (sliding pages)

Tags: jquery, drupal, parallax

I am trying to use ParallaxJS to achieve a similar effect to the [ParallaxJS Demo](http://stolksdorf.github.com/Parallaxjs/), although I am using Drupal 7 and wondering how this effects it.

In general these kind of designs have hardcoded containers for each page, whereas Drupal obviously creates them as separate pages. What would be the best way to create this effect on a Drupal site?

Comment: Not really, I played around with Parallax, slide shows, mouse scroll and all kinds of effects. In the end I based all my solutions on the page--front.tpl.php template and then used each region as an item/slide/page (works all round). I changed the divs to <li> too so it was better for sliders. Need any more advice / pointers?

Comment: And then used different plugins to achieve different affects. Currently set on jCarousel to load the regions and use itemCallIn and itemCallOut animations to do some funky stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The approach I would use is to start with Views (http://drupal.org/project/views).

If you want a page with blocks displaying different node types or entity types you can easily do this in Views. Explaining how Views works is a bit much typing but using it is a real advantage to working with Drupal.

From the docs it seems ParallaxJS allows you to work with basically any elements so you should have get enough markup to make it work from Drupal.

Views can give you a page with the content you want. Making sure the ParallaxJS triggers on it is up to your JS code or your implementation of Drupal hooks. Off the top of my head you could use drupal_add_js in hook_init (arg-function or other methods can be used to check the path) to implement it in a custom module.